# Dynamic update of multiple series in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a `highcharts-chart` with four lines (`series`).
I would like to update each series with one point (`value`) and shift these four lines dynamically (1 in - 1 out) at the same time.
This works with one series in the chart perfectly:

```
chart.series[0].addPoint([x, 5], true, true);
```

Is there a fast way to add the point to all four lines at once?

Hanspeter

Comment: How about a `for` loop ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can can update each series on one line, but only make the last one redraw the chart like so:

```
chart.series[0].addPoint([x, 5], false, true);
chart.series[1].addPoint([x, 5], false, true);
chart.series[2].addPoint([x, 5], false, true);
chart.series[3].addPoint([x, 5], true, true);
```

Here is a JSFiddle illustrating the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/mkremer90/yZSzZ/